# Have `npm version` not prepend "v" to the git tag

Tags: npm

Is there a way to tell `npm version` not to add the "v" prefix to the git tags? The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm using dockerhub to build the node/docker project and the tags is used in the version of the docker image, having a "v" there is unusual and pointless.

Comment: I was curios on how to do the same with yarn and came accross this issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5238

Comment: I have it set as `version-tag-prefix ""` with double quotes in `.yarnrc`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use a `.npmrc` file - you may already have one (it stores your [configuration](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) for npm). You can either have:

- a global one in somewhere like `~/.npmrc`
- or a specific for each project in `/var/myprojects/awesomeproject/.npmrc`

Then, just specify the [tag-version-prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#tag-version-prefix) key in it like:

`tag-version-prefix=""`

Answer (score 18):

alternatively, you can run `npm config set tag-version-prefix ''`

Comment: This would create the prefix for the user running this command for all the projects. It is better to use project-local npmrc file if tag prefix is only required in a single project.

Comment: To create the local version you need to pass the `-L project` argument:  
`npm config -L project set tag-version-prefix 'your-prefix'`

Answer (score 12):

You can also pass the prefix on the command line:

`npm version minor --tag-version-prefix=my-prefix`

I didn't find documentation for this, I read the [source code](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/version.js) and saw they use [libnpmversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libnpmversion) which supports that option.

Comment: This does not seem to work with `npm@6.14.15`

Comment: My bad, it actually **does** work, I was looking at the commit message not the git tag. Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer now...